# Why does assigning an empty delegate to this Unity Event Action on construction make it work? (But it is dead/broken without it?)

Tags: unity, events, objects, unity-ui

I am learning about Actions/Events in Unity and just built a system around them which works. However, it seems I just got lucky and I'm not sure why.

Roughly, my class in a simple illustrative form (skipping the deeper logic and just showing one Action) looks like this:

```
public class ClickableElement: VisualElement {
    public event Action setClickedDownAppearance;

    public ClickableElement() {
        setClickedDownAppearance += delegate { }; //EMPTY DELEGATE LINE NEEDED FOR SCRIPT TO WORK
    }

    private void updateClickState() {
        if (mouseDown) {
            setClickedDownAppearance(); //line that throws the error without the above line present
        }
    }
}
```

Then when I create my element it would be something like:

```
ClickableElement testElement = new ClickableElement();
testElement.setClickedDownAppearance += delegate { testElement.style.backgroundColor = new StyleColor(Color.cyan); };
```

The idea is that I can set the parameters for what it should look like or what functions it should run on clicking when I generate the element.

As I said it works fine just like that.

What I don't understand is if I get rid of the line tagged `EMPTY DELEGATE LINE NEEDED FOR SCRIPT TO WORK` the whole thing breaks. It says `Object reference not set to an instance of an object` when I try to run `setClickedDownAppearance();`.

I actually just got completely lucky in building this because I had some simple debug code added to the blank delegates in the constructor. Without that none of this would have worked. But I'm not sure what the issue is since I barely understand these "event Action" things enough to use them.

If I got rid of the line `setClickedDownAppearance += delegate { };` is there some way I could write `public event Action setClickedDownAppearance;` so that it still "exists" and can function?

Thanks for any clarification.

Comment: Isn't it just that the Event is not initialized if you miss the line? You could do as well a check if it has an action assigned before calling it. Same happens if you call a delegate or unity event without a backing function

Comment: If you are wondering if that is okay to do it like this - yes. It's pretty standard, yes you are going to have an empty delegate there each time it's invoked, so a little performance overhead, but it's so low I don't know if I would ever notice it in my code at least. `public event Action<float> OnVolumeChange = delegate { };` example. You can also do `?` check. More on performance here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/170907/is-there-a-downside-to-adding-an-anonymous-empty-delegate-on-event-declaration .

Comment: Thank you Candid Moon _Max. That syntax was exactly what I was looking for so I don't have to do it in the constructor. I will follow that method. Good to know it is considered a normal approach.

Answer (score 1):

Normally you would subscribe an Action with:

```
action += method;
```

and then when you want to call it:

```
action?.Invoke();
```

so the question mark ensures that it will return and not throw an error if nothing is subscribed.